# Use docker `healthcheck` to wait for `up` command to detach

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, devops

I have the following docker-compose.yml excerpt:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  elastic:
    image: elasticsearch:8.2.3
    container_name: elastic
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    volumes:
      - es_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - target: 9200
        published: 9200
    healthcheck:
      test: curl -s http://elastic:9200 >/dev/null || exit 1
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
    networks:
      - elastic
 
  app:
    build: .
    working_dir: /code/app
    command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --reload
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - ./app:/code/app
    ports:
      - target: 8000
        published: 8000
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      elastic:
        condition: service_healthy
    healthcheck:
      test: curl -s http://app:8000/nexus/health >/dev/null || exit 1
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
    networks:
      - elastic
```

When running `docker compose up -d` I would like this command to only exit when the `app` health check condition is met.

I have found a `--wait` command in the docs but it does not seem to work when I try and run this. Also I would just like to double check if the health check test itself seems valid, I am not sure if the should use the service name or localhost in the path.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem (I'm using `--wait` in my CD pipeline setup, and it works perfectly, after `docker compose up` exit all containers are `healthy`). Please elaborate a bit more on "does not seem to work".

Comment: @SUTerliakov apologies that was a bad explanation... I have fixed this and answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue was that I was using the following command:

```
docker-compose up --wait
```

The problem was that this calls I think an older compose API, and it should be:

```
docker compose up --wait
```